# Is http-only cookie safe?

Tags: javascript, php, html, cookies

I am setting http-only cookie from the server for storing some user info so that i can validate user on backend. Say some hacker steals this cookie from someone's browser and go to my webpage and add the same cookie using document.cookie = "cookie_name = cookie_value" if cookie is not there. If cookie is there then he can delete the existing http-only cookie using chrome developer tool and later add it using  document.cookie = "cookie_name = cookie_value" on his browser.

Now when server gets a call from hacker browser, it gets a cookie set by hacker and would validate it. How can i stop this?

Comment: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/how-to-create-totally-secure-cookies , actually agree don't use them for critical data, but this might help make them more secure in less critical scenarios.

Answer (score 3):

Cookies leave you vulnerable to Cross-Site Request Forgeries and their kin.  Not just hackers stealing cookies, but hackers borrowing a user's browser which already has the cookies.  This is part of why tokens are more common today.

If you have to use cookies, there are various things you can do to make them slightly less insecure--updating the cookie on each request, verifying request IP against sending IP, configuring your web pages not to allow the loading off offsite content, forcing re-login for any major actions, and other user verification means.  None of them is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Simple: You cannot. `http-only` serves a different purpose than validation. Your assumption that a hacker will use a browser is the first problem you have. I would never use a browser for something like that since a browser would restrict me. I would forge a HTTP request with my own tools and send a header with `http-only` and secure and whatever you want me to to your server.

If you want to validate your cookies, you will need to implement your own solution instead of relying on browser mechanisms. You could for example bind the cookie to a certain IP range and add some kind of token to the end of the cookie-key or cookie-value.

In general, do what @bryanx says. DO NOT USE COOKIES TO STORE DATA. They are fine for session tokens and the like.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use cookies.

Cookies are necessary for preserving information between sessions, but any time you leave information on the client, you open yourself up to potential issues like you described. If you only need the information maintained during the user's session, you may want to consider using a $_SESSION instead of a cookie.

If you must use cookies, you may want to consider building out logic that if the cookie doesn't match a previously authenticated device, that you challenge the user again for their credentials. There are many ways to solve for this, just get creative.